# How to make zooming for OpenStreetMap in OpenLayers more sensitive to mouse wheel scrolling?

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap

I have been testing OpenLayers for a while and I notice that the scrolling on OpenStreetMap layer does not make the map zoom in or out as much as I would like it to be. On most occasions, I am only able to zoom in or out by only one level at a time, regardless of the scroll clicks. However, when the base layer is switched to Google Maps, I am able to zoom in and out more with more scroll clicks. You can see the difference with [this](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/osm-google.html) example.

At first, I thought this could be due to some inherent problem with OpenStreetMaps, but after testing its own map on the [main site](http://www.openstreetmap.org/), there seem to be no problem with zooming through multiple levels with a mouse scroll. Am I missing something in the OpenLayers control setting to enable such responsive scrolling behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation doesn't say much about this, but if you examine the script, there is a mousewheel `interval` option:

> ```
> /**
>  * Property: interval
>  * {Integer} In order to increase server performance, an interval (in 
>  *     milliseconds) can be set to reduce the number of up/down events 
>  *     called. If set, a new up/down event will not be set until the 
>  *     interval has passed. 
>  *     Defaults to 0, meaning no interval. 
>  */
> interval: 0,
> ```

This value can be changed by setting the following when declaring map controls:

```
new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(
 {mouseWheelOptions: {interval: 500}}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding the createMap function and define your own scales.
Something like below (just put your own values in the scales):

```
createMap: function(mapDiv) {
    var controls = [new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()];
        options = {
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:2039"),
            displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:2039"),
            units: "m",
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-154106, 360012, 603185, 838233),
            scales: [13000, 7000, 5000, 4500, 3500, 1700, 1000, 500],
            controls: controls
        };           
    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is a solution to the problem. Skipping zoom levels and making it more responsive are two different issues altogether.

Answer (score 0):

When instantiating the OpenLayers Navigation bar, you can define the mouse wheel options [1]. The mouse wheel options are defined at the MouseWheel handler [2]. Here I leave an example:

```
var ctrlNav = new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({
    mouseWheelOptions : {
        interval: 10, //{Integer} In order to increase server performance, an interval (in milliseconds) can be set to reduce the number of up/down events called.
        maxDelta: 1, //{Integer} Maximum delta to collect before breaking from the current interval.
        delta: 1, //{Integer} When interval is set, delta collects the mousewheel z-deltas of the events that occur within the interval.
        cumulative:false, //{Boolean} When interval is set: true to collect all the mousewheel z-deltas, false to only record the delta direction (positive or negative)
    }
});
```

[1] http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/Navigation-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.Navigation.mouseWheelOptions

[2] http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Handler/MouseWheel-js.html